# Project refactored to suppport ARC now while building the project getting error "language not recogonized ml2"

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, xcode4.5

[image]

My project was perfectly building before it is refactored to support arc. Now when the refactoring is applied, it is not building and an error message is shown that language not recogonized. Any work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker command line shows an option "-xml2", which is wrong. You have to find and remove that option from the "Linking" options in the build settings.